# Groovy: How to invoke methods when closure is one of the parameter

Tags: groovy, closures

This is my closure method and i am looking for different ways to invoke this groovy method

```
myMethod(Closure c, def val) {
    if(c)
    c.call()
    println val
}
```

Things i tried:

```
myMethod({/*code*/},"print something")
```

Is there a way i can skip braces or a better way to do the same?

Answer (score 1):

Put the Closure last in the definition:

```
def myMethod(val, Closure c) {
    if(c) c.call()
    println val
}
```

Then you can do:

```
myMethod("print something") { -> println "closure!" }
```

#### Edit

Think you're going to need 2 methods:

```
def myMethod(Closure c) {
    myMethod('default', c)
}

def myMethod(val, Closure c) {
    if(c) c.call()
    println val
}
```

Then you can do:

```
myMethod('tim') { println 'woo' }
```

or

```
myMethod { println 'woo' }
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response, my second argument accepts some default value and it will be used rarely and that is why i kept closure as first param. myMethod(Closure c, def val="default value")

Comment: So why not: `def myMethod(val = 'default', Closure c)`

Comment: Yes, whenever i use this method i should call as below even val is 'default' myMethod('default'){//closure code). I don't want to send default value always as parameter. As val param is least used, i want to keep it as second param

Comment: @Aditya, you can do that too as tim_yates suggests. See here [Demo](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5109993577644032)

Comment: @tim_yates, Learnt from your comment that it is enough to define method as `def myMethod(val = 'default', Closure c)` which works both cases mentioned by OP without needing to define two methods. Looks, second parameter is `closure`, it is possible to have first parameter with default value. https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5109993577644032